# How can I query the database every few seconds?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, this is my code:

```
<?php
//Connect to the database
include("config.php");

//Query the database and get the count  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads");  
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);  
?>
```

How can I make it so it query's the database for the count every few seconds?

Comment: Are you sure this is the best solution?  Assuming that you want to do this from the browser/client, you may end up with a lot of requests going against your database every few seconds.

Comment: That depends.  What do you want to do with $num_rows?  Are you throwing it away? displaying it? emailing it?

Comment: I'm displaying it, example is found at http://squaretise.com/home.php. The big number on the bottom left is the $num_rows

Comment: well for a start don't `select *` rather `select count(id)` ...

Comment: So I should do $result = mysql_query("select count(ads)"); ?

Comment: a web site of adverts and no other content - good luck with that!

Comment: Hm.. what do you mean by 'no other content'? What other content would you expect on such a site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your PHP script separately (in my example below thescript.php)

```
<?php

  //Connect to the database
  include("config.php");

  //Query the database and get the count 
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as num FROM ads");
  $count = mysql_fetch_result($q,0,'num');
  echo $count; 

?>
```

Then use AJAX/javascript/jQuery in your home.php file:

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
      function loadNum()
      {  
        $('h1.countdown').load('thescript.php');
        setTimeout(loadNum, 5000); // makes it reload every 5 sec
      }
      loadNum(); // start the process...
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a very experienced programmer. So, 'thescript.php' should be the file that the code I gave above is on (so, home.php)? Also, what is the need in the datacontainer DIV? Thanks.

Comment: the datacontainer div is to load the contents into from the PHP script. you can of course name it whatever you want to as long as your script loads it into an existing element in the HTML code... AND yes for an AJAX solution just take all the code above and put it in a separate file, I called it thescript.php but you can think of something more clever! :)

Comment: I looked on your page and edited my code above. It is clear that you already have jquery installed. Just put my script code at the end of your HEAD tag and fix the php file...

Comment: so what does `$('h1.countdown')` do?

Comment: @Oliver It gets the result from the counter script and adds it to a H1 element with class `countdown` (existed on the sample page). Now this is a typical problem with external links; The example posted in another comment is not available anymore.