# PHP - Get new value from array after 10 seconds

Tags: php, arrays, timeout

I have an array called test. While looping, I want to get next value from array after 10 seconds. For example, the first value to echo is A.

The value is A. Then, after 10 seconds, the value will be replaced with B. The value is B. After 10 seconds again, the value will be replaced with C. The value is C. It will repeatedly get next value and come back to A and continue the process.

What I get so far is it executes one after another, but not replacing the value. I want just the value changes but the sentence "The value is" stays, not executes all "The value is B","The value is C" and so on.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
<?php

@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',1200);
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$test=array("A","B","C","D","E");

foreach ($test as $value) {
    $var="The value is $value";
    echo $var;
    if(sleep(10)!=0)
    {
        echo "sleep failed script terminating"; 
       break;
    }

    flush();
    ob_flush();

}

    ?>
```

Comment: You know that php runs on server side?

Comment: @u_mulder i'm sorry i don't understand

Comment: you won't achieve this that way - as a server-side language php is executed before the page is fully loaded in your browser, meaning you can't halt the script and expect your browser to display anything coherent (it needs a full html document to be able to render properly, thus the end of the php script and full transfer to the client through http).

Comment: PHP runs on server and web-server sends **all** output of script to your browser. This is not a desktop app.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483690/how-can-i-query-the-database-every-few-seconds

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry, but you can very well use php to implement things apart from the typical client/server setup. php is well suited as local shell language, for example. The fact that you _can_ use php inside a http server does not mean you _have to_...

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that a lot. For me this works without issue:

```
<?php
@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',1200);
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$test=array("A","B","C","D","E");

foreach ($test as $value) {
    echo "The value is $value<br>\n";
    sleep(10);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

The output obviously is:

```
The value is A
The value is B
The value is C
The value is D
The value is E
```

---

Considering your comment here you actually ask for something which you did not say in the question at all: to *overwrite* the visible output with each iteration. That is something completely different. As mentioned in the comments this is different and not trivial, since you have to "take back" something you already flushed.

Here is a working variant for CLI, is displays only one sentence with the capital letter changing every 10 seconds. For a web environment things are more complex, you have to implement some small client side logic removing the previously flushed text again from the DOM. However for that it would be a thousand times easier to just iterate over those letters on the client side directly.

```
<?php
@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',1200);
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$test=array("A","B","C","D","E");

foreach ($test as $value) {
    echo "The value is $value";
    flush();
    sleep(10);
    echo str_pad('', 14, "\x08");
}
```

Comment: what i meant was to echo just one line which is "The value is $value". The value need to change after every 10 seconds, it is replaced. not print another line with new value.

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something completely different. That is not possible by simply appending to the output, since that does not remove that what you have flushed before, obviously. For such thing you need a different approach: on CLI you can simply use a backspace character to "wipe out" the last line,  for a web environment you need to use javascript to implement some client side logic. This was not clear at all from your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for console: just add "backspace" key code (`\x08`) before echoing value

```
<?php
$test=array("A","B","C","D","E");

echo "The value is  ";
foreach ($test as $value) {
    echo "\x08" . $value;
    sleep(10);
}
echo "\n";
```